# sql profiler shows nhibernate running queries twice?

Tags: nhibernate, profiling, sql-server-profiler

I have been doing some performance analysis on an application I am working on. The application is web-based (asp.net) using an old version of NHibernate (1.0) on MSSQL Server (2005).

Running profiler against the application seems to show something a little odd, in that we seem to be querying objects twice, once as a direct query and once wrapped in sp_executesql. for example:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE'
```

Looking at the stats within profiler I can see they are distinct events (the select is recorded as event 45 - SP:StmtCompleted whilst the call to sp_executesql is recorded as event 10 - RPC:Completed).

I have not worked with NHibernate too much before this, but I cannot imagine this is normal behavior. Am I either mis-reading the profile trace (in which case how should I interpret the above), or is there a good reason for this?

If the above is as bad as I think, is there a way to switch this behavior off?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your queries are not run twice. It's just that those 2 events are fired for the same statement.

Comment: ok - so for my understanding, why is one wrapped in sp_executesql, and the second not?

Comment: and why does running an sp_executesql statement manually not reproduce the same behavior?

Comment: i'm not familiar with NHibernate that much, but i'd guess that it happens because of it's command settings. It would seems really strange that they would fire twice.